# How to store user-specific data in a wordpress plugin?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I'm currently developing a wordpress plugin `quotaPlugin`, which needs to store data for each registered user (e.g. certain quotas for a printing service: total budget of pages, pages left to print within this month,...).

Since this data is plugin specific, I do not want to store the data in `wp_users` or `wp_usermeta`.

However, I want to connect the database `wp_quotaPlugin_db` as close as possible to `wp_users`. My current approach is:

```
      $sql_create_table = "CREATE TABLE ".$wpdb->prefix.'quotaPlugin_db'" (                 
        id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,                         
        booked DATE DEFAULT '1999-01-01' NOT NULL,                                                            
        remainingpages SMALLINT NOT NULL,                                     
        UNIQUE KEY id (id)                                                     
      );";

     require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');                 
     dbDelta($sql_create_table);
```

... being completely disconnected from `wp_users`. Since (to my knowledge) FOREIGN KEY is not supported, how can I associate a user with a quota (deleting its entries, when the user is deleted, etc...)

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Even if you don't use a foreign key constraint, you can sill add an uid field that will reference the user id in wp_users.